# Two processes reading and writing a file at same time in c

Tags: c, linux, process

I have two processes that communicate through a text file.
Parent process continuously read data from a file and write to shared_file.

```
              FILE *shared_file = fopen("shared_file.txt", "w");

              while(fscanf(fp, "%s", currentLine) != EOF){
                if (strstr(currentLine, "$GPGLL")) {
                  sleep(1);

                  fputs(data, shared_file);
                  fputs("\n", shared_file);
                  fflush(shared_file);
                }
              }
```

Child process read a new line and write it to another file.

```
  FILE *shared_file = fopen("shared_file.txt", "r");
  FILE *another_file = fopen("another_file.txt", "w");

  char currentLine[256];

  while(TRUE){
    if (fgets(currentLine, sizeof(currentLine), shared_file)) {
      fputs(currentLine, another_file);
      fflush(another_file);
    }
    else{
      sleep(1);
      clearerr(another_file);
    }
  }
```

This code is not working for me. Child process only writes few lines into "another_file.txt".

Any leads would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You read into `currentLine`; you write from `data` (never changing it).  Is that part of your problem?

Comment: Shouldn't `clearerr(another_file);` actually be `clearerr(shared_file);` ??

Comment: @AdrianMole The error was just that. Thank you very much.